# Click on dynamically added element in Magnific Popup not detected. Trying to navigate to next item on click of current item in ajax gallery

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm creating an image gallery where the full size images are presented in a lightbox. The contents of the lightbox are ajax-loaded HTML from an external file. I'm using the [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) script for this behavior. I'm trying to make it such that you can navigate to the next gallery image by clicking anywhere directly on the current image displayed in the lightbox. The problem is that I haven't been able to detect the click event, although it's clearly inserted into the DOM.

**Main view:** `main.html`

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="gallery.php?photo=image-1.jpg">thumb-1.jpg</a>
    <a href="gallery.php?photo=image-2.jpg">thumb-2.jpg</a>
    <a href="gallery.php?photo=image-3.jpg">thumb-3.jpg</a>
</div>
```

**Lightbox contents:** `gallery.php`

```
<?php echo '<img class="item" src="img/' . $_GET['photo'] . '" >'; ?>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.gallery').each(function() { 
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'ajax',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true,
            navigateByImgClick: true
        }
    });
});
```

While I don't see the `navigateByImgClick` option documented, it seems to be intended to set things up such that clicking the current gallery item will take you to the next gallery item. However, at least in my testing, this doesn't seem to work for ajax galleries (when `type` is set to `ajax`). So what I've done is added a snippet to see if the click event is being detected:

```
$('.item').on('click', function() {
    alert('click detected');
});
```

`.item` is the gallery item's selector. However, the click is never detected (the alert is not presented on click).

First, why isn't the click being detected?

Second, how to set up [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to load the next gallery item when using an ajax gallery?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Need to assign `.mfp-img` class to the image. Now it works. This can be discovered by this part of the magnific popup source:

```
if(gSt.navigateByImgClick) {
    mfp.wrap.on('click'+ns, '.mfp-img', function() {
        if(mfp.items.length > 1) {
            mfp.next();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```